# external HDD stopped working

Tags: mount, hard-drive

Hi guys I usually work with large files on an external HDD (1 Tb Toshiba) but after rebooting the laptop for an update I can't see it anymore.

I am working with Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

When I do `dmesg | tail`  I get the following:

```
[ 2605.778978] usb usb1-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 2606.430884] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd
[ 2606.431085] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2606.638937] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2606.846862] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 32, error -71
[ 2606.974698] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 33 using xhci_hcd
[ 2606.974806] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2607.182967] usb 1-1: Device not responding to setup address.
[ 2607.390882] usb 1-1: device not accepting address 33, error -71
[ 2607.391006] usb usb1-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
```

I cannot manually mount it using `fdisk -l`  (no additional sd* after I plug it in)

I tried on a mac laptop and also there I plug the disk and it doesn't recognize it. I have white lights blinking on the device and instead of getting a steady blue light it turns off and I can hear it stops rotating.

Comment: open up applications, search for disks. see if you can detect your drive, scan and repair

Comment: Does the external disk enclosure have its own external AC power supply? Do you have access to a desktop computer?

Comment: You are troubleshooting faulty hardware now, which is not an Ubuntu-specific problem. If you manage to get it to work again, back up your data immediately to more reliable hardware, because it might not work for long.